# En un foreach mostrar los 3 primeros de un modo y el resto de otro

Tags: php, html, condiciones, foreach

Lo que quiero hacer es que al recorrer una tabla con un `foreach`, los 3 primero registros que saca me los muestre con un `html` y el resto con otro `html`.

```
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM vivienda");
    foreach ($results as $res):
      $precio = $res['precio'];
      $etiqueta = $res['etiqueta_id'];

     <div>Mostrar con un div</div>
     <!--y al ser mayor de 3-->
     <div>Mostrar con otro div</div>

  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Hice algo parecido en laravel pero aquí no se como hacerlo.

```
@foreach ($cincoViviendas as $vivienda)
   @if ($loop->iteration <= 3)

 <div>Mostrar con un div</div>

@else

 <div>Mostrar con otro div</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Declara un contador en cero antes del bucle `for` y lo incrementas al final de cada iteración, entonces en cada iteración capturas con un `if` el valor del contador y aplicas la lógica correspondiente. ¿Has probado eso?

Comment: No se aplicar lo que me comentas @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Si más o menos seria así, pero como lo hago para que el php se parta y pueda poner html en el div

Continuando con la respuesta de alanfcm, podes usar imprimir el html que necesites usando "echo". Los elementos luego se pueden concatenar adentro del html. Como se muestra a continuación:

```
foreach ($results as $i => $res):
  $precio = $res['precio'];
  $etiqueta = $res['etiqueta_id'];
  if ($i <= 3) {
    echo '<div><span>'.$precio.'</span><span>'.$etiqueta.'</span></div>';
  } else {
    <!--y al ser mayor de 3-->
    echo '<div><h1>'.$precio.'</h1><h2>'.$etiqueta.'</h2></div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Que tiene de diferente esta respuesta q la de Alan?

Comment: La impresion del html y la concatenacion de los valores. Como digo, es una continuacion a la respuesta de alan. Lamentablemente no puedo comentar aun en respuestas ajenas... :(

Comment: Entonces por favor edita tu respuesta y explícalo, pues solo colocar código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Creo que esta claro. No coloque solo codigo. Te invito a leer la respuesta.

Comment: ya la leí y por eso te hago la observación, por que la respuesta que coloques debe ser claramente explicada, decir que corregiste y por que, siempre siempre considera que esto que pones no solo va para quien pregunta sino para usuarios futuros y no a todos les va a quedar claro lo que pones

Comment: Entiendo. Gracias por la sugerencia. Edite mi respuesta para que quede mas clara. :D

Answer (score 0):

El metodo `foreach` de php te permite agregar una variable para llevar el indice de las iteraciones

```
foreach ($results as $i => $res):
  $precio = $res['precio'];
  $etiqueta = $res['etiqueta_id'];
  if ($i <= 3) {
    <div>Mostrar con un div</div>
  } else {
    <!--y al ser mayor de 3-->
    <div>Mostrar con otro div</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Si más o menos seria así, pero como lo hago para que el php se parta y pueda poner html en el div

Comment: Hola @alanfcm, como puedo hacerlo como te digo???